# How to filter multiple layers by same attribute in ArcGis with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I need to filter features by one specific attribute which is same for every layer that I am using. I tried this tutorial https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/featurefilter-attributes/ which workrs fine but just for one layer. How can I modify this code to add another layers?
I want to filter on client side. My code is the same as in tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply the filter to each layer view, there is no general filter on the map.

I should not be much effort though, just iterate over the layers on the map, an in case of `FeatureLayer` apply filter to the `FeatureLayerView`.

[ArcGIS API JS - Map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#layers)